# Prove that for every simple graph $G=(V,E):\, \frac{1}{2} \chi(G) (\chi(G)-1) ≤ |E|$

Tags: graph-theory

I am a first year math student, and I'm studying some exercises for my graph theory exam. This exercise I didn't understand very well:

> Prove that for every simple graph $G=(V,E)$  $$\frac{1}{2} \chi(G)
>  (\chi(G)-1) ≤ |E|$$

A hint would be appreciated.

Comment: @Shahab Thanks! This one can get closed, I understand it now.